# Resource file not showing its properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, resources, class-library

I have one issue while using Resource file. I am using Resource file to keep the variables with its values. Now when i access the Resource file it doesn't show keys(properties) until i assign it to another variable. i.e

```
var tempVar = ResourceFileName.Variable1 // it shows Variable1 in intellisense.
```

but if i use

```
ResourceFileName.Variable1 //it doesn't show up.
```

Even if i return statement i.e

```
return ResourceFileName.Variable1 // doesn't work.
```

PS: I have used Resource file in Class Library Project and accessing them by adding references.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Amod

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys it was all my fault. I was using it outside the method. My bad!!